# How do I add rows to a Javascript DataTable from a string containing an array?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to make a Google chart which pulls the data from a hidden field on a web page.

If I add the data in directly via data.addRows it works fine:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Rainfall');     

      data.addRows([[new Date(2000, 8, 5), 56], [new Date(2000, 8, 6), 22], [new Date(2000, 8, 7), 44], [new Date(2000, 8, 8), 40], [new Date(2000, 8, 9), 62]]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Rainfall'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

However, if I try and create a string which contains the array and then add it using addRows it doesn't work:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Rainfall');     

      var myData = "[[new Date(2000, 8, 5), 56], [new Date(2000, 8, 6), 22], [new Date(2000, 8, 7), 44], [new Date(2000, 8, 8), 40], [new Date(2000, 8, 9), 62]]"

      data.addRows(myData);

      var options = {
        title: 'Rainfall'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

How can I add the data in the string to the DataTable?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oo5w6ghf/4/

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - I need to add "eval" to the string:

```
 var myData = eval("[[new Date(2000, 8, 5), 56], [new Date(2000, 8, 6), 22], [new Date(2000, 8, 7), 44], [new Date(2000, 8, 8), 40], [new Date(2000, 8, 9), 62]]")
```

Comment: So long as you're aware of the advice against using eval and are happy to take on those risks, it's fine. I don't see any other way immediately of doing this, but you just need to realize that using eval is like juggling a running chainsaw - fine if you know what you're doing and can control your environment. Dangerous and bloody otherwise.